# giga/tera hertz timer? super fast spinning disc?

Tags: motors, vacuum

How would I go about detecting a very small amount time dilation

I want to accelerate something and measure the time dilation even if I reach 1km/s time dilation is very small but it looks just barely within reach.

I'm currently thinking a spinning disc, but the numbers are all just a bit beyond what I know how to build. For the timer I obviously want maximum resolution.

I could spin a 0.6m diameter disc at 1000hz(60,000rpm *fixed conversion error).. I suppose... in a vacuum...errrrmmm... I'm trying not to kill myself.....

I want to test a hypothesis...

cosmic inflation redshift destroys energy

cosmic inflation create new space

new space has vacuum energy

HYPOTHESIS 1: expansion red-shift of certain energies(eg photons) has space-energy conservation. space to energy / energy to space conversion is occurring, and if you factor in space as energy there is conservation.

I roughly calculated the energy the numbers and they fall within reasonable range, but I cant think of a way to test it except correlating expansion rate with radiation energy traversing various regions of spacetime,

So I while I'm working on that I moved on to hypothesis 2, which is much more of a long shot, because relative velocity redshift doesn't have lost energy, the energy is conserved as momentum. But I figure is one form of redshift involves space-energy conversion then perhaps so do the other types of redshift.

Hypothesis 2 : All red/blue shifting includes an energy to space conversion. While traveling at high speed if light is emitted forward it is blue shifted and converts some space into energy, emit light backwards and it creates space.

So my plan is to arrange a time dilation test by accelerating a time counter. Sandwich it between 2 powerful LED arrays, one facing forward and one facing backwards. check if time dilation is affected when light is emitted forward and/or backwards. (try both pointing at the counter and both pointing, always aligned so lights are pointed parallel to motion vector)

Comment: Possibly more related to physics than engineering.

Comment: Spinning a 0.6m diameter disk at 3.6 million RPM without killing yourself is more about engineering than physics IMO. But it's probably impossible, using any material the OP is likely to be able to afford. Even 36,000 RPM would be a serious professional engineering design project. The fact that the OP hasn't even correctly converted "Hz" to RPM in the question doesn't bode well, IMO.

Comment: haha.. yes.. you are right.. oops.. hours instead of minutes.

Comment: but still 0.3m radius by 60,000rpm = centripetal accelerations of 4.3 million g... so I am looking an increasing disc size decreasing rotation speed

Comment: @vasten increasing the radius will make the disk heavier, and it will still break because of the stress levels at the hub.